# SQL Server: what are all these names/editions?

Tags: sql-server

When trying to download SQL Server to learn database development on Windows, the user is confronted with many editions and codenames with no explanation. Wikipedia and casual googling were not very helpful, so if there is a resource that I have missed, preferably a Microsoft resource, then I would very much appreciate a link.

Some of the listed technologies include Denali, RC0, R2, Express Edition, Standard Edition, Azure, Management Studio, Evaluation Edition. Where are all these terms defined?

Comment: I think casual googling will actually get you the answers to all the terms you list there.  Prepend any of those terms with 'Microsoft', 'MS SQL', or 'Windows' should get you the answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has several **versions**: 7.0, 2000 (8.0), 2005 (9.0), 2008 (10.0), 2008 R2 (10.5) and the next one up - 2012 (11.0 - this is not available yet, and was code-named "Denali").

Besides that, each version of SQL Server comes in various **editions** - **Express** is the free version (free to use), **Standard** is the first paid version with limited feature set, **Enterprise** is the full package with all the features.

**SQL Azure** is Microsoft's offering of "SQL Server in the cloud", e.g. it's not a product that you download, install and use - it's a service that you sign up for and use. You don't need to install anything locally.

**Management Studio** is the tool used by all the SQL Server version from 2005 on up to look at the database, execute queries etc.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx
The "Editions" dropdown points to pages about the various versions, which more or less explain what they do and what they're for.

As with all Microsoft products, "RC" means Release Candidate; not an official release yet, but having received enough testing that they feel safe to make it available to daring customers.

Answer (score 1):

For Complete list of Versions and download link,s please check, http://www.sqlserver-training.com/sql-server-version-builds-list-complete/-

[Complete List of SQL Server Verions / Builds](http://www.sqlserver-training.com/sql-server-version-builds-list-complete/-)